# VS Web Deploy - Server name

Tags: visual-studio, azure, publish

In Visual Studio 2017 Publish method - web deploy, how do you find the azure Server name to enter on the configuration screen? In the past I used below but it no longer works:
 https://1005db481f3448ec91913fb98b9b279e.cloudapp.net:8172/MsDeploy.axd

Answer (score 0):

Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow!

Assuming you're trying to publish to an Azure Web App, if you're not sure about what the Server and Site names are, I'd suggest you download the `.publishsettings` file from the Azure portal using "Get publish profile" option, and import that into VS. Check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/deploying-to-production#deploy-the-application-to-staging) section for a detailed walkthrough.

It would usually look something like this:

[image: Publish wizard]

Or if you have an Azure VM as the publish target, use the [Azure Virtual Machines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/publish-web-app-from-visual-studio) option in the publish wizard to simplify deployment.

Note: The link mentioned in the question is broken. So if you still see issues despite trying the above options, please post a screenshot and we can troubleshoot further.